# Como agrupar valores de arrays que tengan un mismo valor de indice

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
[0] => Array
   (
        [Contrato] => 0122PS0001251477
        [0] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Rut] => 8035133
        [0] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Nombre] => LUIS JAIME GUERRERO GUERRERO
        [0] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Contrato] => 0122PS0001251477
        [0] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Rut] => 11847294
        [0] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Nombre] => SANDRA ESTHER AREVALO YEVENES
        [0] => 2
    )
```

Y quisiera tener alguna idea de como poder agruparlos de esta manera:

```
[0] => Array
    (
       [Contrato] => 0122PS0001251477 
       [Rut] => 8035133
       [Nombre] => LUIS JAIME GUERRERO GUERRERO
       [0] => 1
    )
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php
$data = Array(0 => Array
   (
        'Contrato' => '0122PS0001251477',
        0 => 1
    ),    
1 => Array
    (
        'Rut' => 8035133,
        0 => 1
    ),    
2 => Array
    (
        'Nombre' => 'LUIS JAIME GUERRERO GUERRERO',
        0 => 1
    ),    
3 => Array
    (
        'Contrato' => '0122PS0001251477',
        0 => 2
    ),    
4 => Array
    (
       'Rut' => 11847294,
        0 => 2
    ),    
5 => Array
    (
        'Nombre' => 'SANDRA ESTHER AREVALO YEVENES',
        0 => 2
    )
);
$datos = Array();
$newDato = Array();
$j = 1;
foreach ($data as $i => $dato) {
    if($dato[0] == $j) {
        foreach($dato as $key => $value) {
            $newDato[$key] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        $j++;
        $datos[] = $newDato;
        $newDato = Array();
        foreach($dato as $key => $value) {
            $newDato[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
$datos[] = $newDato;
var_dump($datos);
?>
```

Comment: funciona bien hasta que el número no es consecutivo, aún no puedo formar el arreglo, gracias de todos modos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, puede que esto te sirva, si no es exactamente lo que buscas indicamelo y lo ajusto:

```
    <?php 
    
    $collection = array(
        array
       (
            'Contrato' => '0122PS0001251477',
            0 => 1
        ),array
        (
            'Rut' => '8035133',
            0 => 1
        ), array
        (
            'Nombre' => 'LUIS JAIME GUERRERO GUERRERO',
            0 => 1
        ),array
        (
            'Contrato' => '0122PS0001251477',
            0 => 2
        ),
    array
        (
            'Rut' => '11847294',
            0 => 2
        )
    ,
     array
        (
            'Nombre' => 'SANDRA ESTHER AREVALO YEVENES',
            0 => 2
        )
    );
    
    
    $result = [];
    
    foreach ($collection as $array){
        foreach ($array as $key=>$item ){
    
           //Si aún no existe el indice lo creo y añado el array de la misma iteración pues
            //como lo acabo de crear está vacio.
          if (!isset($result[$key])){
              $result[$key] = array();
              array_push($result[$key],$item);
          }
          //Si existe el array con dicho indice, pero aun no existe ese valor, lo añado
          else if (isset($result[$key]) and !in_array($item,$result[$key],false)){
              array_push($result[$key],$item);
          }
    
        }
    
    }
    echo "Resultado\n";
    var_dump(var_export($result, true));

?>
```

### OutPut

```
array (
  'Contrato' => 
  array (
    0 => '0122PS0001251477',
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  'Rut' => 
  array (
    0 => '8035133',
    1 => '11847294',
  ),
  'Nombre' => 
  array (
    0 => 'LUIS JAIME GUERRERO GUERRERO',
    1 => 'SANDRA ESTHER AREVALO YEVENES',
  ),
)
```

Saludos!.

PD.: He actualizado mi respuesta.